# Postgres current_time evaluation

Tags: postgresql, time

I'm trying to display status information in the Messages pane for a long-running function in Postgres 9.3.0. Postgres is evaluating `localtime` only once, when function execution begins, and NOT as I call the value. It's outputting the same value repeatedly. How can I fix this?

I'm iterating through a cursor like this:

```
FOR record IN cursor LOOP
    PERFORM otherFunction(<id field from the record>);
    If mod(i,100)=0 THEN
        RAISE NOTICE '% pct complete',round(i::numeric/recordcount::numeric*100);
        RAISE NOTICE '%', localtime;
        i=i+1;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use [`clock_timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).

Answer (score 1):

See [the user manual for current date/time](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).

`localtime`, like `current_timestamp`, is fixed across the transaction.

Use `clock_timestamp` if you want a fresh time at each call. Be aware that unlike `localtime` it returns `timestamp with time zone`, so you may wish to `at time zone` convert it, or cast it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Milen and Craig.